# make regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

How to make a regex for this in Python?

```
[1,12:12] call basic_while1() Error Code: 1046. No database selected
```

I tried this `'^\[(\d+),([0-9:]+)\]\s+(.+)$'` but I am not getting any matches on this kind of input:
`['1','12:12', 'call basic_while1()' ,'Error Code: 1046. No database selected'`]  using that regex.

> and what is the regex if I want to get output like `['Error Code: 1046. No database selected']`

How to make a regex for this so that I can get matches?

Comment: Try `^\[(\d+),(\w+)]\s+([^:]+):(.+)$`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ociGE/3).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew a) your demo does not seem to match b) you replaced `[0-9:]` with `\w` which does not include `:`.

Comment: Ok, `^\[(\d+),([0-9:]+)]\s+([^:]+):(.+)$` , yeah. [V2](https://regex101.com/r/8ociGE/2) should work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: There is no colon `:` after `call basic_while1()`

Comment: You use 3 capturing groups, but your desired result seems to have 4, this seems wrong/confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I'm making a (risky) assumption that there will always be the substring `Error Code` in your texts. So I modified your regex to `'^\[(\d+),([0-9:]+)\]\s+(.+)\s+(Error\sCode:.+)$'`. Running this in the shell:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '[1,12:12] call basic_while1() Error Code: 1046. No database selected'
('1', '12:12', 'call basic_while1() Error Code: 1046. No database selected')
>>> re.match('^\[(\d+),([0-9:]+)\]\s+(.+)\s+(Error\sCode:.+)$', text)
<re.Match object; span=(0, 68), match='[1,12:12] call basic_while1() Error Code: 1046. N>
>>> _.groups()
('1', '12:12', 'call basic_while1()', 'Error Code: 1046. No database selected')
```

If you want a list, simply use a type-cast.

```
>>> list(_)
['1', '12:12', 'call basic_while1()', 'Error Code: 1046. No database selected']
```

<sub>Side note: the `_` in the above commands is a shortcut telling the Python shell to reuse the previous result (in this case, the `re.Match` object and then the `groups()` result).</sub>

Altogether:

```
matches = re.match('^\[(\d+),([0-9:]+)\]\s+(.+)\s+(Error\sCode:.+)$', text)
if matches is not None:  # if there is no match, re.match returns None
    print(list(matches.groups()))
```

> and what is the regex if I want to get output like `['Error Code: 1046. No database selected']`

You could simply index the last element of the list by using `[-1]` then wrap it with brackets to make it a list.

```
print([matches.groups()[-1]])  # output => ['Error Code: 1046. No database selected']
```

Comment: that assumption is totally right, and that code gives me a perfect sol . Thanks to you

Comment: I just updated my Question , can you please ans it @
TrebuchetMS

Answer (score 0):

You are matching 3 capturing groups and you need a 4th one which starts after the `()`. After the closing `]` you could add a non greedy match to match till the opening and closing parenthesis:

`^\[(\d+),(\d+:\d+)\]\s+(.*?\(\))\s+(.*)`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bbaRCQ/1)

That would match:

- `^` Start of the string
- `\[` match `[`
- `(\d+)` Capture in a group 1+ digits
- `,(\d+:\d+)` Match comma and capture in a group 1+ digits followed by a colon and 1+ digits. (Or `[0-9:]+` but that would be a broader match)
- `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace characters
- `(.*?\(\))` Capture in a group  any character 0+ times non greedy and then match `()`
- `\s+(.*)` Match 1+ whitespace characters and capture in a any character 0+ times